# Calculating a total based on previous rows with matching ID

Tags: rank, calculation

I have a table with account information, including the starting balance and payments.  I am trying to find a way to determine the balance as each payment comes in.  Each row has an account number, the starting balance, the payment date and the payment amount.  Most accounts only have one payment per month so its easy to determine.  Others may make multiple payments. So I need to be able to see what the adjusted balance is for each payment. I have used rank over to rank the payments for each month and my table currently looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+
| Account |  St_Date  | St_bal  |  Pay_dt   | Pay_amnt | Rank |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/23/2019 |    -2000 |    1 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/24/2019 |    -4500 |    2 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/26/2019 |    -4500 |    3 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 9/2/2019  |    -4000 |    4 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 9/3/2019  |    -4000 |    5 |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+
```

I have tried using lag and joining the table back onto itself but not getting the desired results.

I would like each row that is greater than rank 1, to take the st_bal and subtract each payment from the ranks above it to get an adjusted balance amount.  So for the line where the rank is 1, the adj_bal is blank because it is the first.  For rank 2, the adj_bal should be the starting balance minus the payment from rank 1(it should not use the payment from rank 2), for rank 3 the adj_bal should be the starting balance minus the payment from rank 1 and rank 2(not to include rank3, as its the line its being calculated on) and so forth. However, if the calculation would take the adjusted balance below 0 I just want it to populate 0.

```
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+---------+
| Account |  St_Date  | St_bal  |  Pay_dt   | Pay_amnt | Rank | adj_bal |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+---------+
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/23/2019 |    -2000 |    1 |         |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/24/2019 |    -4500 |    2 | 5544.61 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 8/26/2019 |    -4500 |    3 | 1044.61 |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 9/2/2019  |    -4000 |    4 | 0.00    |
|   12345 | 8/16/2019 | 7544.61 | 9/3/2019  |    -4000 |    5 | 0.00    |
|   67890 | 8/20/2019 | 8563.36 | 8/25/2019 |     -900 |    1 |         |
|   67890 | 8/20/2019 | 8563.36 | 8/27/2019 |     -600 |    2 | 7663.36 |
|   67890 | 8/20/2019 | 8563.36 | 8/29/2019 |    -1500 |    3 | 7063.36 |
|   67890 | 8/20/2019 | 8563.36 | 9/1/2019  |     -500 |    4 | 5563.36 |
+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+----------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need the rolling sum of payments per account and statement period. I'm deducting the most current row's payment amount since your balances are staggered. (I guess that's supposed to mean balance prior to the payment rather than after?)

```
case
    when "rank" = 1 then null
    -- /* or */ when row_number() over (partition by account, st_date order by pay_dt) = 1
    when st_bal - pay_amnt +
        sum(pay_amnt) over (partition by account, st_date order by pay_dt) > 0 
    then st_bal - pay_amnt +
        sum(pay_amnt) over (partition by account, st_date order by pay_dt)
    else 0.00
end
```

This does sort of assume there aren't multiple payments per date. That's fixable by adding rank to the summation ordering. The window could also have been expressed as `sum(pay_amnt) over (partition by account, st_date order by pay_dt rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)` rather than adjusting but this won't work on all platforms. Make sure not to try math on `null` values.

https://rextester.com/GXRWLA9434

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have just recently learned to use rank() over (partition) and did not realize there were other uses for the partition command.  This has worked exactly as I have needed.  I even inserted some test data to check different scenarios and this always calculates as intended.